# PHP in HTML code

Tags: php, html

I wrote PHP in HTML code :

```
<div id="loginContainer">
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['id_client']){
  print "<a href=\"#\" id=\"loginButton\">";
} else {
  print "<a href=\"#\" id=\"loginButton3\">";
}
?>
</a></div>
```

but this appears in the output page: `;}else { print`

How can I get the PHP to execute?

Comment: Does the page have a .php extension?

Comment: Just a tip, it would be much easier on you to keep track of quotes if you surrounded the strings in single quotes, so you wouldn't have to escape double quotes inside the string and possibly make a mistake sometimes.

Comment: This question just asked may help you also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604336/php-include-function-inside-an-html-file#comment25622804_17604336

Comment: This could be better written as `<a href="#" id="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_client'] ? "loginButton3" : "loginButton" ?>"></a>`

Comment: @AndréDion I hate it when people moan about 1 line if statements saying they harder to read! Tidy code!

Comment: @Jonnny : Thanks , it was .html extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your file have a `.php` extension (or is your server configured to process that file as PHP)?

If not, the entire block:

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['id_client'])
{
print "<a href=\"#\" id=\"loginButton\">
```

Is being treated as one big, ugly, invalid HTML tag, leaving the rest to be visible.

Make sure the file has a `.php` extension.

Comment: Thank's , the file was .html ( problem solved )

Comment: is there an yway to run php in .html ????